# Get Max value for subset of rows in column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have data that has different values at different times for each patient `ID` in long format, using `tidyr::gather()` that looks something like this:

```
ID    TIME    VALUE
1     10      14
1     20      34
1     30      35
2     10      15
2     20      14
2     30      11
3     10      16
3     20      64
3     30      55
```

I want to add a new column called `MAX` containing the time for when each patient had their max `VALUE`, something like this:

```
ID    TIME    VALUE    MAX
1     10      14       30
1     20      34       30
1     30      35       30
2     10      15       10
2     20      14       10
2     30      11       10
3     10      16       20
3     20      64       20
3     30      55       20
```

Here is my attempt:

```r
data$MAX <- data %>% 
    dplyr::group_by(data$ID) %>% 
    filter(VALUE$ID == max(VALUE$ID))
```

Do you have any suggestions to do this?

EDIT:

Error message:

```r
## Warning: Problem with `mutate()` input `MAX`.
## i NAs introduced by coercion
## i Input `MAX` is `data$TIME[which.max(data$VALUE)]`.
## i The error occurred in group 1: data$ID = "pat1".
## Warning in which.max(data$VALUE): NAs introduced by coercion
```

I see this error message repeatably for different `ID`s in the output after running my .Rmd script

EDIT 2:

I removed all other variables for simplicity:

```
## 'data.frame'  : 1500 obs. of  13 variables:
##  $ ID         : chr  "pat1" "pat10" "pat100" "pat11" ...
##  $ TIME       : chr  "Time.0.15.h" "Time.0.15.h" "Time.0.15.h" "Time.0.15.h" ...
##  $ VALUE      : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
```

Please note that most `VALUE` rows are > 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `which.max` to create a numeric index and subset the corresponding 'TIME' after grouping by 'ID'

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
     group_by(ID) %>%
     mutate(MAX = TIME[which.max(VALUE)])
     # // if the column is not numeric, convert to numeric
     # mutate(MAX = TIME[which.max(as.numeric(VALUE))]) 
     # it may be better to convert it before that
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   ID [3]
#     ID  TIME VALUE   MAX
#  <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1    10    14    30
#2     1    20    34    30
#3     1    30    35    30
#4     2    10    15    10
#5     2    20    14    10
#6     2    30    11    10
#7     3    10    16    20
#8     3    20    64    20
#9     3    30    55    20
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), TIME = c(10L, 
20L, 30L, 10L, 20L, 30L, 10L, 20L, 30L), VALUE = c(14L, 34L, 
35L, 15L, 14L, 11L, 16L, 64L, 55L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried this, seems to work. Will accept as correct answer after cooldown timer. However, 1 more quick questions, if that is ok ? I get `NAs introduced by coercion` in `which.max(data$VALUE)` when running this on some of the values. I guess it is because i dont have VALUE row for some TIME. How do I ignore these ?

Comment: @Carlton Do you have `NA` elements in 'TIME' or 'VALUE' column.  Suppose if the 'TIME' is NA for that max 'VALUE', it can happen.  Can you check `colSums(is.na(data))`

Comment: Running `colSums(is.na(data))``shows no 0 in all fields

Comment: @Carlton Usually the `which.max` will return the index even if there is a single non-NA ie. `which.max(c(1, NA, 3))#[1] 3`.  But, if you don't have any non-NA for a particular group, then it is problematic

Comment: @Carlton can you show the `str(data)` Is the column 'VALUE', numeric

Comment: @Carlton Can you update the post with a `dput` of the example that gives this issue?  So that i can check the structure

Comment: @Carlton please update in your post with the `dput` so that I can test it instead of my post

Comment: @Carlton Your 'VALUE' column is `character` class and not `numeric`

Comment: Added `str()` but my dput is very large as you can see from the edit. Do you still want it posted ?

Comment: Ok, so I should just convert it to numerical ?

Comment: @Carlton I would do `data %>%
     group_by(ID) %>%
     mutate(MAX = TIME[which.max(as.numeric(VALUE))])`  There may be some warning if there are non-numeric values in that column which gets converted to `NA`

Comment: Thanks for your help & time. All seems to be in order now

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. How to do save this as the existing dataframe? if I run `str(data_combine)` after running the code above, I still see my old dataframe without the MAX column. Also, after running the code above, it says that there are 2 new columns ``data$ID` <chr>, CMAX <chr>`

Comment: @Carlton You need to assign i.e. `data <- data %>% group_by(ID) %>%mutate(MAX = TIME[which.max(as.numeric(VALUE))])` or  you can use `%<>%` operator from `magrittr` i.e. `data %<>% group_by(ID) %<>%mutate(MAX = TIME[which.max(as.numeric(VALUE))])`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225380/discussion-between-carlton-and-akrun).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to use dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
# Create reprex
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ID, ~TIME, ~VALUE,
1, 10, 14,
1, 20, 34,
1, 30, 35,
2, 10, 15,
2, 20, 14,
2, 30, 11,
3, 10, 16,
3, 20, 64,
3, 30, 55,
4, 30, NA,
4, 20, NA,
5, 10, 10,
5, 20, 30
)

        df_max <- df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number(desc(VALUE)),         # creates an id with 1 being the max VALUE
         MAX = case_when(rn == 1 ~ TIME)) %>%  # when the max VALUE is 1 then TIME. Not using TRUE ~ anything results in NAs
  fill(MAX, .direction = "downup") %>%         # copies the value up and down where there is an NA within the grouped ID
  select(-rn) %>%                              # remove the row number
  ungroup()
```

I've added a couple of extra rows, one ID with NA values to show the fill() doesn't automatically fill those because of the group_by() on the ID.